# How to run full-import command using SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Plz suggest, how I can run command=full-import?

```
 SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");
```

And what then...

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava) page and the spellcheck example there. It uses the old `CommonsHttpSolrServer` but it's similar to what you want. This code should be what you're looking for, even though I haven't tried it yet:

```
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("qt", "/dataimport");
params.set("command", "full-import");
QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

In SolrJ 7

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient; 
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery; 
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException; 
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient; 
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;

SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/test_core").build();

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(); 
query.set("qt", "/dataimport"); 
query.set("command", "full-import"); 

QueryResponse response = client.query(query);
```